# Transaction - Concurrency Code Organization Issues. - Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, session, transactions, code-organization

**Setup**

I do some heavyweight business logic in my service layer where I invoke different methods of DAO one after the other. Like:

```
myDao.persistOperationOne(myPersistentObject);
//.....Other business logic goes here
myDao.anotherPersistOperation(anotherPersistObject);
```

Now each one of them open their own session and committ the transaction at the end. Its kinda important for me that both persistOperationOne() and anotherPeristOperation() happen in some kind of a transaction context.

**Question**

How can I club DAO logic in two different methods in one session/transaction context. I don't like creating session inside service layer, it simply isnt the concern of services isn't it? 
At the same time clubbing both the DAO logic in one DAO method will cause service layer business logic to be moved to DAO, which is undesirable as well?

Is there a way to neatly organize code in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

> I don't like creating session inside service layer, it simply isnt the
>   concern of services isn't it?

Actually, it's service responsibility to manage transactions. As in your case, there may be multiple operations on database which need to be done all at once or none, so best is to wrap them in a service and commit from there.